# Shifting integer using shiftopearator

Tags: java

How does doing

```
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(43 >> 24));
```

gives me a result as zero?

Where as right shift << gives me 101011000000000000000000000000 . Can anybody explain with example how does this happen?

Comment: Could you at least motivate your question by describing your expectation? Because it is quite obvious that `43 >> 24` *is* zero, as well as any `43 >> t` for `t > 5` (and `< 32`, but that's another story).

Answer (score 6):

43 is represented as

```
101011
```

in binary. Shift that right by 24 bits and you get

```
0
```

which is

```
0
```

in binary.

Consider reading about the `>>` and `<<` operators, [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) for example.

Comment: I am actually dividing the integer into 4 8bits values. For that i came to know i need to shift the int value like >> 24, >>16 , >>8 and then the int . This give me result as 0,0,0,43 .Thus i divided 32bits into 4 8bit values. But i don't know the logic behind it? how does >>24gives me 8bit value . How is it related to int value 43?

Comment: @user3025547 An `int` is represented as 4 bytes. Each byte is 8 bits. If you shift the `int` by a certain range, you can get the value of each byte.

Comment: 4bytes of int=43 is represented as 0 0 0 43 ? How do we represent this in binary?

Comment: @user3025547 No 43 in binary is what I showed in my answer, `101011`. If you want the full 32 bits, it's `0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0010 1011`.

Comment: Consider i am storing each 8bits into 4 bytes->and array of byte[]. And when i want to get back the orginal int =43 value from the value at first 4 index of array i do bytes[0] << 24 | (bytes[1] & 0xFF) << 16 | (bytes[2] & 0xFF) << 8 | (bytes[3] & 0xFF) . Can you explain the logic behind this?

Comment: @user3025547 Learn what `<<` and `|` and `&` mean and then apply them. You are trying to reconstruct an `int` from 4 `byte` values.